# Hyperledger V1.0 user enrollment using fabric-ca-client, JWT token expired

Tags: node.js, express, postman, access-token, hyperledger-fabric

I have some issue while interacting with Hyperledger fabric V1.0. I'm testing the balance-transfer example on Ubuntu machine. I dockerized Node.js API in order to interact with fabric from remote application. Then I have exposed port 4000 on Docker for node.js app and made a bridge with outside port of container to access the server. Yesterday I could execute [sample REST API requests](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/master/balance-transfer#sample-rest-apis-requests)  locally from the command line. For example, I could register/enroll the user in the network, create a channel, etc. However with the Postman tool, I was getting errors like:

- Error: Enrollment failed;
- ECONNREFUSED localhost:8054, ECONNREFUSED localhost:7054, port number
  depends on what user token I was using for the request.
- Error: This client instance must be assigned a user context.

That is my first problem.

The second problem came today. Node.js uses JWS tokens for secure authentication and those tokens were expired after 10 hours and it is normal since it is configured that way in config.json file. But what I couldn't understand is that I even can not authenticate a new user from localhost with the command line. For instance, this login request doesn't return anything, it's not executing:

```
curl -s -X POST http://localhost:4000/users -H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'username=Jim&orgName=org1'
```

POST request from POSTMAN gives me the following error:

```
[2017-09-26 06:46:57.514] [DEBUG] SampleWebApp - End point : /users
[2017-09-26 06:46:57.514] [DEBUG] SampleWebApp - User name : Toko
[2017-09-26 06:46:57.514] [DEBUG] SampleWebApp - Org name  : org1
[2017-09-26 06:46:57.519] [DEBUG] Helper - [FileKeyValueStore.js]: FileKeyValueStore.js - constructor
[2017-09-26 06:46:57.523] [DEBUG] Helper - [FileKeyValueStore.js]: FileKeyValueStore -- getValue
[2017-09-26 06:46:57.525] [DEBUG] Helper - [FileKeyValueStore.js]: FileKeyValueStore.js - constructor
[2017-09-26 06:46:57.526] [DEBUG] Helper - [FileKeyValueStore.js]: FileKeyValueStore -- getValue
[2017-09-26 06:46:57.602] [DEBUG] Helper - [utils.CryptoKeyStore]: This class requires a CryptoKeyStore to save keys, using the store: {"opts":{"path":"/tmp/fabric-client-kvs_peerOrg1"}}
[2017-09-26 06:46:57.603] [DEBUG] Helper - [FileKeyValueStore.js]: FileKeyValueStore.js - constructor
[2017-09-26 06:46:57.604] [DEBUG] Helper - [utils.CryptoKeyStore]: _getKeyStore returning ks
[2017-09-26 06:46:57.604] [DEBUG] Helper - [crypto_ecdsa_aes]: generateKey, store.setValue
[2017-09-26 06:46:57.605] [DEBUG] Helper - [ecdsa/key.js]: ECDSA curve param X: ea4b0229247d282daf293fc11728b4a4a4bddcabecffca02f7bcde725f0738c7
[2017-09-26 06:46:57.606] [DEBUG] Helper - [ecdsa/key.js]: ECDSA curve param Y: f6a41282f86bcd853fddca402f1d47868a864b46adc8abd4e8a5864778f18de5
[2017-09-26 06:46:57.613] [DEBUG] Helper - [FileKeyValueStore.js]: FileKeyValueStore -- setValue
[2017-09-26 06:46:57.675] [ERROR] Helper - Error: Calling enrollment endpoint failed with error [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7054]
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/fabric-ca-client/lib/FabricCAClientImpl.js:711:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:310:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1277:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
[2017-09-26 06:46:57.676] [DEBUG] Helper - Toko failed to register
[2017-09-26 06:46:57.677] [ERROR] Helper - Toko enrollment failed
(node:17) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Cannot save null userContext.
(node:17) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: Cannot read property '_enrollmentSecret' of null
```

If any of you already faced the same issue please guide me. Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE**
Docker containers:

```html
40b9eb090695        dev-peer1.org1.example.com-mycc-v0-f76f22af4a360dd2172e04459b1687f933a29d4b8d6c97ea0a4a21144a108361   "chaincode -peer.a..."   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours                                                           dev-peer1.org1.example.com-mycc-v0
2a7d3271c32a        dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycc-v0-f021beca29998638e0bb7caa7af8fda7f1e709518214a3181d259abcb2347093   "chaincode -peer.a..."   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours                                                           dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycc-v0
b5c6f5d3a036        myapp/node-app                                                                                         "npm start"              2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:9999->4000/tcp                           myapp_node
33b7c1355832        hyperledger/fabric-peer                                                                               "peer node start"        2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp   peer0.org1.example.com
cf9b72d928ef        hyperledger/fabric-peer                                                                               "peer node start"        2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:7056->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7058->7053/tcp   peer1.org1.example.com
4de554d07d7b        hyperledger/fabric-peer                                                                               "peer node start"        2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:8051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8053->7053/tcp   peer0.org2.example.com
c627b28ebd4a        hyperledger/fabric-peer                                                                               "peer node start"        2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:8056->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8058->7053/tcp   peer1.org2.example.com
e02b4ffe531b        hyperledger/fabric-ca                                                                                 "sh -c 'fabric-ca-..."   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:8054->7054/tcp                           ca_peerOrg2
91dc8167caed        hyperledger/fabric-orderer                                                                            "orderer"                2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                           orderer.example.com
d150835f7826        hyperledger/fabric-ca                                                                                 "sh -c 'fabric-ca-..."   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                           ca_peerOrg1
```

Since I'm getting error on localhost:7054 while connecting to ca_peerOrg1 - `Error: Calling enrollment endpoint failed with error [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7054]` 
I inspected ca_peerOrg1 container by running this command: `docker inspect --format='{{range $p, $conf := .NetworkSettings.Ports}} {{$p}} -> {{(index $conf 0).HostPort}} {{end}}' d150835f7826` 
and I got the following IP address: 172.20.0.2. Does it mean that fabric-client is not configured properly ? 
`/users` method is requesting localhost:7054, but actually ca_peerOrg1 has different ip - 172.20.0.2. If it's like this how I can configure the ip address of sdk?

**SOLVED**
I solved my problem by changing the *localhost* with my Ubuntu *server ip address* in [app/network-config.json](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release/balance-transfer/app/network-config.json) file. Now I can access API's **user** function with the following url: `http://serverIP:PublicPort/users` and enroll users from Postman.